# How do you link to answer?

Tags: support

Usually when need to link an answer i only know how to link the entire question, but how do you link a specific answer from the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/why-does-my-object-move-faster-at-45-degrees-than-at-90-degrees) question, go to the first answer and look below it you'll find the following, `share` `edit` `flag`, `share` will give you a link like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22904/8957).

Comment: ah i see, i thought that would just contain ways to post to social media but i found the link now, thanks!